# How to display SPECIFIC laravel validation error in view, not all of them

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, validation, view

The problem I am having is I have multiple validation rules on my date of birth field.

```
        @if($errors->has('dob'))
            <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block error">
                @foreach($errors->get('dob') as $message) 
                    {{ $message }}
                @endforeach
            </span>
            <script>$('#dob').addClass('formError');</script>
        @endif
```

This will print out ALL of the errors.

I only want to print out the 'required' validation rule if it gets triggered, I am handleing the other validation in the front end.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but you probably shouldn't depend on front end validation only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue a while back. You can only access the error message bag via its public methods, $errors->all(), $errors->get(), $errors->first() etc.The first two methods return numeric arrays of the messages. Therefore, there's no way to filter by the validation name. So the best thing is to know the order of the messages based on your validation rules. So if for example, 'required' is the second rule defined for that field, you can access it by using it's index. Like this.

```
@if($errors->has('dob'))
        <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block error">
                {{ $errors->get('dob')[1] }}
        </span>
        <script>$('#dob').addClass('formError');</script>
    @endif
```

Sorry for bad english. Hope you understand. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the foreach and do

```
{{ $errors->first('dob') }}
```

Comment: Can you be sure the 'required' rule will be first?

Comment: If required is the first rule required will be first.